# Traverse through JSON tree and manipulate its data/structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a function that can traverse through JSON tree and change its data/structure. I managed to make it traverse to every node and read data, but stuck at changing its data/structure part.

```
function jsonTraverser(tree){
    $.each(tree, function(index, val){
        if(val.tag == 'button'){
            delete val[index];
        }
        if(val.children){
            jsonTraverser(val.children);
        }
    })
}
jsonTraverser(json_obj);
```

From the code above, it should remove JSON node that has tag equals to button. While it seems to works but it doesn't remove a node, while changing its tag works just fine. Do you have any solution for this problem?

PS: If you need sample of JSON tree, here it is.

```
[
  {"tag":"div","id":"0","class":"sgph","children":[
    {"tag":"div","data-scoretype":"","class":"sgi","id":"1","children":[
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"up","html":"ขึ้น"},
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"down","html":"ลง"},
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"edit","html":"เปลี่ยนกลุ่ม"},
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"del","html":"ลบกลุ่ม"}
    ]},
    {"tag":"div","class":"scph","children":[
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"score_type","class":"add","html":"เกณฑ์การให้คะแนน"}
    ]},
    {"tag":"div","class":"stph","children":[
      {"tag":"div","class":"sti","id":"3","children":[
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"up","html":"ขึ้น"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"down","html":"ลง"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"edit","html":"เปลี่ยนหัวข้อ"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"del","html":"ลบหัวข้อ"}
        ]},
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"add","html":"เพิ่มหัวข้อ"}
    ]}
  ]},
  {"tag":"div","id":"1","class":"sgph","children":[
    {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"add","html":"เพิ่มกลุ่ม"}
  ]}
]
```

Comment: v.children or val.children?

Comment: val[i] is nothing, val contains named properties like "tag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled a few variable names wrong. For example, "v" should have been "val".
jsonTraverse should also `delete` from tree, not from val, as tree holds the list of children.

```
function jsonTraverser(tree){
    $.each(tree, function(index, val){
        if(val.tag == 'button'){
            delete tree[index];
        }
        if(val.children){
            jsonTraverser(val.children);
        }
    })
}
```

Note that you must deal with the case where the root itself has tag 'button'.